# Customer Persist Override gives NextMove issue while deleting

Tags: acumatica

I am getting the following error when trying to delete a customer:

```
An unhandled exception has occurred in the function 'MoveNext'
```

[image]

I think i need to add this if statement or something similar.

```
if(Base.BAccount.Cache.GetStatus(CCustomer) != PXEntryStatus.InsertedDeleted || Base.BAccount.Cache.GetStatus(CCustomer) != PXEntryStatus.Deleted)
```

I found a couple of links with this issue but non that is specific to the customer page.

```
public delegate void PersistDelegate();
    [PXOverride]
    public void Persist(PersistDelegate baseMethod)
    {
        using (var scope = new PXTransactionScope())
        {
            Customer row = this.Base.BAccount.Current;
            if (row.ParentBAccountID == null)
            {
                CustomerMaint businessAccount = PXGraph.CreateInstance<CustomerMaint>();
                PXResultset<Customer> Children = PXSelect<Customer, Where<Customer.parentBAccountID, Equal<Required<Customer.bAccountID>>>>.Select(Base, row.BAccountID);
                foreach (Customer item in Children)
                {
                    businessAccount.Clear();
                    businessAccount.BAccount.Current = PXSelectorAttribute.Select<Customer.bAccountID>(this.Base.BAccount.Cache, item.BAccountID) as Customer;
                    item.TermsID = row.TermsID;
                    item.Status = row.Status;
                    Contact defContact = PXSelect<Contact, Where<Contact.bAccountID, Equal<Required<BAccount.bAccountID>>, And<Contact.contactID, Equal<Required<BAccount.defContactID>>>>>.Select(businessAccount, item.BAccountID, item.DefContactID);
                    defContact.EMail = this.Base.DefContact.Current.EMail;
                    businessAccount.DefContact.Update(defContact);
                    businessAccount.BAccount.Update(item);
                    businessAccount.Save.PressButton();
                }
            }
            baseMethod();
            scope.Complete();
        }
       }
```

I am hoping there is a check I can build in or something that can eliminate the MoveNext error when deleting.

Comment: it looks like the main error is an object reference error. Debug reveal any null objects  in your action override. The stack trace give any line numbers to review?

Comment: Saving in persist method is a very common anti-pattern. Does the error disappear if you remove the persist override? If yes consider a design change to avoid persisting records in the persist event handlers.

Comment: Hi @HB_ACUMATICA, Yes the error does disappear if I remove the persist override. What is the best practice to save other records? To give a bit more background I use this save(persist) to save child customers details from the parent customer

Comment: Would be to add another dataview in the graph extension to hold the other customer. I will post an answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the same pattern as the base CustomerMaint class which uses `UpdateChildAccounts` and `GetChildAccounts` methods to modify the child accounts.

```
    protected virtual void Customer_PrintDunningLetters_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        Customer row = (Customer)e.Row;
        CheckExcludedFromDunning(cache, row);
        UpdateChildAccounts<Customer.printDunningLetters>(cache, row, GetChildAccounts(sharedCreditPolicy: true));
    }

    protected virtual void Customer_Status_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        Customer row = e.Row as Customer;
        if (row == null) return;

        if (row.ParentBAccountID == null)
        {
            Func<Customer, bool> func;
            string newValue = GetSharedCreditChildStatus(row.Status, out func);
            UpdateChildAccounts<Customer.status>(cache, row, GetChildAccounts(sharedCreditPolicy: true).Where(func), newValue);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void Customer_ConsolidateToParent_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        Customer row = (Customer)e.Row;
        if (row == null) return;

        if (row.ParentBAccountID == null)
        {
            IEnumerable<Customer> childs;
            string message = PXMessages.LocalizeFormatNoPrefix(Messages.RelatedFieldChangeOnParentWarning,
                PXUIFieldAttribute.GetDisplayName<Customer.consolidateToParent>(sender));

            if ((childs = GetChildAccounts()).Any() && e.ExternalCall)
            {
                if (CurrentCustomer.Ask(message, MessageButtons.YesNo) == WebDialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    UpdateChildAccounts<Customer.consolidateToParent>(sender, row, childs);
                }
            }

            row.SharedCreditPolicy &= row.ConsolidateToParent;
        }
        else if (row.SharedCreditPolicy == true && row.ConsolidateToParent != true && (bool?)e.OldValue == true)
        {
            sender.SetValueExt<Customer.sharedCreditPolicy>(row, false);
        }
    }

protected virtual void UpdateChildAccounts<Field>(PXCache cache, Customer parent, IEnumerable<Customer> enumr, object sourceValue = null)
    where Field : IBqlField
{
    if (PXAccess.FeatureInstalled<FeaturesSet.parentChildAccount>() &&
        parent != null &&
        parent.ParentBAccountID == null)
    {
        sourceValue = sourceValue ?? cache.GetValue<Field>(parent);
        foreach (Customer child in enumr)
        {
            if (sourceValue != cache.GetValue<Field>(child))
            {
                cache.SetValue<Field>(child, sourceValue);
                cache.Update(child);
            }
        }
    }
}

protected virtual IEnumerable<Customer> GetChildAccounts(bool sharedCreditPolicy = false, bool consolidateToParent = false, bool consolidateStatements = false)
{
    if (PXAccess.FeatureInstalled<FeaturesSet.parentChildAccount>())
    {
        PXSelectBase<Customer> select = new PXSelect<Customer, Where<Customer.parentBAccountID, Equal<Current<Customer.bAccountID>>>>(this);
        if (sharedCreditPolicy)
        {
            select.WhereAnd<Where<Customer.sharedCreditPolicy, Equal<True>>>();
        }
        if (consolidateToParent)
        {
            select.WhereAnd<Where<Customer.consolidateToParent, Equal<True>>>();
        }
        if (consolidateStatements)
        {
            select.WhereAnd<Where<Customer.consolidateStatements, Equal<True>>>();
        }

        return select.Select().RowCast<Customer>();
    }

    return Enumerable.Empty<Customer>();
}
```

Otherwise create a new DAC inheriting from Customer to hold the children and create a data view for them in the graph. You can then modify the children in that data view and they will be persisted automatically when user invoke the Save action from UI.

```
[Serializable]
public partial class OtherCustomer : Customer
{
    public new abstract class bAccountID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<bAccountID> { }
}

PXSelect<OtherCustomer, Where< … >> OtherCustomers;
```